# Is there way to close "find action" or other dialogs by `control + g`

Tags: rubymine

I'm using emacs-like key bind with RubyMine.
To close a dialog like `Find Action`, I have to put `ESC`.
Is there way to config `control + g` for that action?

I couldn't find the key mapping for it.

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to close dialogues in rubymine with `C-g`?

Comment: Please post a link to the `elisp` source code responsible for `Find Action`.

Comment: @MrBones Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @lawlist ah, I'm using key config like emacs in `RubyMine`. There is no `elisp` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Keybinding for close is not there for now, It is implemented as popup and select+tab or unfocus (click on other item) or escape can close it.
Here is code for reference
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/util/gotoByName/ChooseByNameBase.java#L612